# ReRender woes the apex:messages

Tags: visualforce

VF Page:

```
    <apex:form >
<apex:messages styleClass="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--error customMessage" />
      <!-- CREATE NEW ACCOUNT FORM 
      <form class="slds-form--stacked"> -->      
       <fieldset class="slds-form--compound">  
       <legend class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-title--caps"><b>Enaggement Details</b></legend>                    
                      <div class="form-element__group">  
                        <div class="slds-form-element__row slds-large-show">
                          <label class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--1-of-2" style="width: 49.8%;">
                            <span class="slds-form-element__helper">Cohort:</span>                                                      
                            <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" value="{!selectedCohort}" size="1" id="coho">                          
                                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!cohortOptions}"/>
                                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!lcOptionslist}" rerender="lcmain">                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                 </apex:actionSupport>
                           </apex:selectList>
                          </label>  
                          <label class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--1-of-2" style="width: 49.8%;">
                            <span class="slds-form-element__helper">Site:</span>                                                      
                            <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" value="{!selectedSite}" size="1">                          
                                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!siteOptions}"/>
                           </apex:selectList>
                          </label>
                          <label class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--1-of-2" style="width: 49.8%;">
                            <span class="slds-form-element__helper">View:</span>                                                      
                            <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" value="{!assignUassign}" size="1">                          
                                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!assignUassignOptions}"/>
                           </apex:selectList>
                          </label>                  
                        </div> 
                        <legend class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-title--caps"><b>Track Details</b></legend>   
                        <div class="slds-form-element__row slds-large-show">
                          <label class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--1-of-2" style="width: 49.8%;">
                            <span class="slds-form-element__helper">Learning Community:</span>                                                      
                            <apex:selectList id="lcmain" styleclass="slds-input" value="{!globalselectedLC}" size="1">                          
                                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!lcOptions}"/>
                                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!applyGlobalchanges}" rerender="lcoption" >                                                       
                                 </apex:actionSupport>
                           </apex:selectList>
                          </label> 
                          <label class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--1-of-2" style="width: 49.8%;">
                            <span class="slds-form-element__helper">Track:</span>                                                      
                            <apex:selectList id="trackmain" styleclass="slds-input" value="{!globalselectedTrack}" size="1">                          
                                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!trackOptions}"/>
                                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!applyGlobalchanges}" rerender="track,trackv">                                                                                                               
                                 </apex:actionSupport>
                           </apex:selectList>
                          </label>                         
                        </div>                      
                      </div>
                    </fieldset> 

              <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                   <apex:commandButton style="background-image:url({!URLFOR($Resource.SiteSamples,'img/warning.png')});color:#fff;background-color:#0074d9;height:35px;width:100px;border-width:0px;background-repeat:no-repeat;cursor:pointer;" id="filter" styleclass="btn btn-primary" value="Go" reRender="studentTable,studentTable1" action="{!fetchEngagements}"  status="statusSaveTrip"/> &nbsp;
                  <apex:commandButton style="background-image:url({!URLFOR($Resource.SiteSamples,'img/warning.png')});color:#fff;background-color:#0074d9;height:35px;width:150px;border-width:0px;background-repeat:no-repeat;cursor:pointer;" value="Update Records" action="{!updateEngagements}" rerender="myForm,thePanelWrapper" status="statusSaveTrip"  />   
              </div>           
     <!-- </form> -->
      <br/>      
        <apex:outputpanel id="studentTable1">
            <apex:outputPanel id="datePanelContainer1" rendered="{!itFailed}">
        <div class="slds-card">
                      <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                        <div class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                          <div class="slds-media__figure slds-icon slds-icon-standard-contact slds-icon--small">
                            <img src="/resource/LDS/assets/icons/standard/contact_60.png" alt="Placeholder" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="slds-media__body">
                            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-truncate">Engagement ({!wrapList.size})</h2>
                          </div>
                        </div>                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-card__body">
                        <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal slds-no-row-hover">
                          <thead>
                            <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                              <th class="slds-cell-shrink" scope="col">
                                <label class="slds-checkbox">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="options" onchange="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')" />
                                  <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                                  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select All</span>
                                </label>
                              </th>
                              <th>Student Engagement</th>
                              <th>Learning Community</th>
                              <th>Current Track</th>
                              <th>New Track</th>
                              <th class="slds-cell-shrink" scope="col"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!wrapList}" var="e">
                                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                  <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-shrink" data-label="Select row Engagement">
                                    <label class="slds-checkbox">                          
                                      <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.selected}" id="inputId" />          
                                      <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select row Engagement</span>
                                    </label>
                                  </td>         
                                  <td role="gridcell" data-label="Account Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub"><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.name}" /></div>
                                  </td>  
                                  <td>
                                    <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" value="{!e.selectedLC}" size="1" id="lcoption">                                                                              
                                          <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedCLC}"/> 
                                                <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/> 
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                  </td>   
                                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.selectedNTrack}" id="track" /></td>  
                                  <td> 
                                     <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" id="trackv" value="{!e.selectedNTrack}" size="1">                                                                           
                                           <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedTrack}"/>
                                                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refreshPage}" rerender="track" > 
                                                       <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/>
                                           </apex:actionSupport>                                                                            
                                     </apex:selectList>
                                  </td>    
                                </tr>  
                            </apex:repeat>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>                      
                    </div>  
                    </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>        

</apex:form>
```

Issue:

`<apex:messages styleClass="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--error customMessage" />` is not rendering if I use reRender in Command button.

If I remove reRender, then error messages is showing up.

Can any one help me here?

Regards,
Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use apex:outputPanel

`<apex:outputPanel id="messagesPanel">
     <apex:pageMessages id="errorMessages" styleClass="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--error customMessage"/>
</apex:outputPanel>`

Comment: This one worked perfectly.:)

Answer (score 0):

In your apexMessage add the id:

```
<apex:messages id="errorMessage" styleClass="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--error customMessage" />
```

And in your command button add the id into rerendered page:

```
<apex:commandButton style="background-image:url({!URLFOR($Resource.SiteSamples,'img/warning.png')});color:#fff;background-color:#0074d9;height:35px;width:100px;border-width:0px;background-repeat:no-repeat;cursor:pointer;" id="filter" styleclass="btn btn-primary" value="Go" reRender="studentTable,studentTable1,errorMessage" action="{!fetchEngagements}"  status="statusSaveTrip"/>
```

Then you should be fine. You just need to rerender the pageMessage part as well.

Comment: I tried the approach, no luck. it is not working:(